# Pass settings from one Windows Form to another

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have a form with a check box and if checked then the text in a different form will be all caps.  I think my problem is that I make a new instance every time and just want to get the current state of the checkbox.

```
 public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public bool bChecked = false;

    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form4_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.checkbox = checkBox1.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.checkbox;
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            bChecked = true;
        }
    }
}

public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    Form4 frm4 = new Form4();
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(frm4.bChecked.Equals(true))
        {
            textBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: There are hundreds of questions here on how to do this. And yes, you need to not create a new form. That will *never* work. Pass the existing one on the constructor, or through a method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new instance of `Form4`:

```
Form4 frm4 = new Form4();
```

Then it's not referring to the current instance, but some new in-memory one which is never shown to the user.

Instead, require a reference to an instance on the constructor:

```
Form4 frm4;

public Form3(Form4 form4Instance)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    frm4 = form4Instance;
}
```

Elsewhere in your application, when you create and show `Form3`, you'll need to supply it a reference for the existing `Form4`:

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form4(someReferenceToForm4);
frm3.Show();
```

There are a few directions you could take this.  For example, if `Form3` doesn't *need* a reference to `Form4` but can sometimes use one, then supply both constructors:

```
public Form3()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public Form3(Form4 form4Instance)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    frm4 = form4Instance;
}
```

And perform a `null` check before using it:

```
if (frm4 != null)
    if (frm4.bChecked.Equals(true))
        textBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```

But the point is, you need a reference to the actual already-existing object.  `Form4` isn't the object, it's the blueprints for creating an object.  If you create a second one, it's not the same object.  It might be identical in the same way that two houses built from the same plans are identical.  But they're not the same house.